# Curve C of genus 2 whose equation satisfies equation in Igusa invariants, but where Jac(C) does not split

Tags: elliptic-curves, jacobians

The background question is: Let $C$ be a curve of genus $2$ over a field $k$. When is there a degree $2$ morphism from $C$ to an elliptic curve (and therefore an isogeny from the Jacobian $\mbox{Jac}(C)$ to a product of elliptic curves)?

[On the homepage for their paper](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/~nbruin/splitigusa), Bruin and Doerksen list some equations for the absolute Igusa invariants of $C$ and degree 2, 3 and 4 of the morphism. If $\mbox{Jac}(C)$ is split, then the invariants satisfy the respective polynomial equation. On the other hand, their method suggests the converse may not hold.

Does anyone know a curve whose invariants satisfy the equation, but whose Jacobian is not (2,2)-split?

Comment: Do you mean a degree two morphism from $C$ to an elliptic curve? (It doesn't make sense to say that a map from a surface to a curve has degree two.)

Comment: Of course, thanks for that. Just to clarify further, I'm really only asking for an example (or a hint how to obtain one), not for an answer to the 'background question'.

Comment: Also, my answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109879/ may be helpful.